# Using ruby to delete duplicate words from text file

Tags: ruby, duplicates, readfile

How would I use ruby to delete duplicate lines of word from a text file?
for example:

file reads =

```
line 1 = 345 
line 2 = 234
line 3 = 456
line 4 = 789
line 5 = 234
line 6 = 345
```

I'm trying to write a script where it would read the lines of the file and delete the duplicates. Therefore after the script has been executed the output would be:

file reads =

```
line 1 = 345
line 2 = 234
line 3 = 456
line 4 = 789
```

The function would have deleted the duplicate lines containing 234 and 345.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the ruby-on-rails tag since this is a general Ruby question.

Comment: Are the  `line x = ` bits part of the file?

Comment: ok @AndyWaite gotcha

Comment: and no, @steenslag they're not :\ my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
require 'set'

def copy_unique_lines(source, target)
  lines = Set.new

  File.open(target, 'w') do |out|
    File.open(source, 'r').each_line do |line|
      if lines.add?(line)
        out << line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In which `source` and `target` are file paths:

```
copy_unique_lines('path/input.txt', 'path/output.txt')
```

Comment: this was actually easier for me to understand, however, it didn't delete any of the duplicates. just moved the unique lines to another, which is almost as good. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
lines = File.read('/path/to/file')
lines.split("\n").uniq.join("\n")
```

Comment: what am i supposeed to do with that line of code? In other words, where do I add that in my script? with readfile something?

Comment: i guess i can readlines and then do an .each called "lines" 
will i have to enter it into the file again?

Comment: Yeah I suppose you have to do a: lines = File.readlines() first

Comment: I'm using integers, so doe that affect the lines of code you mentioned? because the above doesn't delete duplicates. :\ 
@shevy